# Efficient XSLT pipeline in Java (or redirecting Results to Sources)

Tags: java, xslt, dom, sax, pipeline

I have a series of XSL 2.0 stylesheets that feed into each other, i.e. the output of stylesheet A feeds B feeds C.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?  The question rephrased is: how can one efficiently route the output of one transformation into another.

Here's my first attempt:

```
@Override
public void transform(Source data, Result out) throws TransformerException{
    for(Transformer autobot : autobots){
        if(autobots.indexOf(autobot) != (autobots.size()-1)){
            log.debug("Transforming prelim stylesheet...");
            data = transform(autobot,data);
        }else{
            log.debug("Transforming final stylesheet...");
            autobot.transform(data, out);
        }
    }
}

private Source transform(Transformer autobot, Source data) throws TransformerException{
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    autobot.transform(data, result);
    Node node = result.getNode();
    return new DOMSource(node);
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a DOM to sit in between transformations, and although it is convenient, it's non-optimal performance wise.

Is there any easy way to route to say, route a SAXResult to a SAXSource?  A StAX solution would be another option.

I'm aware of projects like [XProc](http://xproc.org), which is very cool if you haven't taken a look at yet, but I didn't want to invest in a whole framework.

Comment: "for(Transformer autobot : autobots){" Priceless :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found this: [#3. Chaining Transformations](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2009/01/xml-and-xslt-tips-and-tricks-for-java.html) that shows two ways to use the **TransformerFactory** to chain transformations, having the results of one transform feed the next transform and then finally output to system out.  This avoids the need for an intermediate serialization to String, file, etc. between transforms.

> When multiple, successive
>   transformations are required to the
>   same XML document, be sure to avoid
>   unnecessary parsing operations. I
>   frequently run into code that
>   transforms a String to another String,
>   then transforms that String to yet
>   another String. Not only is this slow,
>   but it can consume a significant
>   amount of memory as well, especially
>   if the intermediate Strings aren't
>   allowed to be garbage collected.
>
> Most transformations are based on a
>   series of SAX events. A SAX parser
>   will typically parse an InputStream or
>   another InputSource into SAX events,
>   which can then be fed to a
>   Transformer. Rather than having the
>   Transformer output to a File, String,
>   or another such Result, a SAXResult
>   can be used instead. A SAXResult
>   accepts a ContentHandler, which can
>   pass these SAX events directly to
>   another Transformer, etc.
>
> Here is one approach, and the one I
>   usually prefer as it provides more
>   flexibility for various input and
>   output sources. It also makes it
>   fairly easy to create a transformation
>   chain dynamically and with a variable
>   number of transformations.
>
> ```
> SAXTransformerFactory stf = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
>
> // These templates objects could be reused and obtained from elsewhere.
> Templates templates1 = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
>   getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyStylesheet1.xslt")));
> Templates templates2 = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
>   getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyStylesheet1.xslt")));
>
> TransformerHandler th1 = stf.newTransformerHandler(templates1);
> TransformerHandler th2 = stf.newTransformerHandler(templates2);
>
> th1.setResult(new SAXResult(th2));
> th2.setResult(new StreamResult(System.out));
>
> Transformer t = stf.newTransformer();
> t.transform(new StreamSource(System.in), new SAXResult(th1));
>
> // th1 feeds th2, which in turn feeds System.out.
> ```

Comment: Great, that looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Just curious - what did you search on to find that?  My google-foo must be rusty.

Comment: Actually, your question reminded me of some code that I had seen implemented a while back.  I knew that it used a saxtransformerfactory, so I googled: "saxtransformerfactory chain transformations".  It does seem oddly hard to find, considering how much code/logic/trouble it saves when you want to pipeline transforms.

Comment: According to http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/?page=6, one can test if transFact.getFeature(SAXTransformerFactory.FEATURE) to be able to safely cast to SAXTransformerFactory.

Comment: Should you not close the streams that you get from getResourceAsStream? To me this looks like a resource leak.

Answer (score 3):

Related question [Efficient XSLT pipeline, with params, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517352/efficient-xslt-pipeline-with-params-in-java) clarified on correct parameters passing to such transformer chain.

And it also gave a hint on slightly shorter solution without third transformer:

```
SAXTransformerFactory stf = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Templates templates1 = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyStylesheet1.xslt")));
Templates templates2 = stf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyStylesheet2.xslt")));

TransformerHandler th1 = stf.newTransformerHandler(templates1);
TransformerHandler th2 = stf.newTransformerHandler(templates2);

th2.setResult(new StreamResult(System.out));

// Note that indent, etc should be applied to the last transformer in chain:
th2.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

th1.getTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(System.in), new SAXResult(th2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to stick to DOM as you're doing, because an XSLT processor would have to build a tree anyway - streaming is only an option for very limited category of transforms, and few if any processors can figure it out automatically and switch to a streaming-only implementation; otherwise they just read the input and build the tree.

Comment: This is not correct. Behavior is implementation dependent.  The Java W3C DOM implementation is very inefficient and most implementations use a more efficient internal representation of this DOM. So the accepted answer *does* improve performance over "stick to DOM".