# Is daisy chaining xslt an accepted practice?

Tags: xslt

I have a situation where I think I need to daisy chain my xslt transformation (i.e. that output of one xslt transform being input into another). The first transform is rather complex with lots of xsl:choice and ancestor xpaths. My thought is to transform the xml into xml that can then be easily transformed to html.

My question is 'Is this standard practice or am I missing something?'

Thanks in advance.

Stephen

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete code example. :)

Comment: Yes, it is accepted, but not always necessary. If you are using Java, the Transformerfactory can be configured to chin successive transforms and avoid unnecessary parsing operations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312406/efficient-xslt-pipeline-in-java-or-redirecting-results-to-sources/1319774#1319774

Answer (score 10):

**Performing a chain of transformations is used quite often in XSLT applications**, though doing this entirely in XSLT 1.0 requires the use of the vendor-specific `xxx:node-set()` function. In XSLT 2.0 no such extension is needed as the infamous RTF datatype is eliminated there.

**Here is an example** (too-simple to be meaningful, but illustrating completely how this is done):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="vPass1"
        select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>2</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>10</num>
<num>14</num>
<num>18</num>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **In the first step the XML document is transformed** and the result is defined as the value of the variable `$vrtfPass1`. This copies only the `num` elements that have odd value (not even).
2. **The `$vrtfPass1` variable, being of type RTF, is not directly usable for XPath expressions** so we convert it to a normal tree, using the EXSLT (implemented by most XSLT 1.0 processors) function `ext:node-set` and defining another variable -- `$vPass1` whose value is this tree.
3. **We now perform the second transformation in our chain of transformations** -- on the result of the first transformation, that is kept as the value of the variable `$vPass1`. Not to mess with the first-pass template, we specify that the new processing should be in a named mode, called "pass2". In this mode the value of any `num` element is multiplied by two.

**XSLT 2.0 solution** (no RTFs):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vPass1" >
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your situation (or may become your situation):

1. Transform initial xml to mediary xml.
2. Maybe transform mediary xml into final1_html.
3. Maybe transform mediary xml into final2_html (not at all like final1_html).

or

1. Transform initial xml into mediary xml.  This is reasonably likely to change over time.
2. Transform mediary xml to final_html.  This in not likely to change over time.

Then it makes sense to use a two step transformation.

If this is your situation:

1. Transform initial xml to mediary xml.
2. Transform mediary xml to final_html.

Then consider not two stepping.  Instead just perform one transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think it was *standard* practice, in particular since you can transform one XML dialect directly to another.

However, if the processing is complex, splitting it to several steps (applying a different transform in each step) can indeed simplify each step and make sense.

It really depends on the particular situation.