# XSL transformation of an input XML using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am just trying to understand the ways how an input XML can be transformed using XSLT file using Java coding.

There are many questions more or less related to my question but i am not getting clear picture so i have put my question in a simple understandable way.

Can anyone help me with different possiblilities and also a simple example to understand the transformation using java.

Comment: Do you want to use the API in the Oracle JRE or do you want to use a particular XSLT processor (for instance Saxon 9 provides XSLT 2.0 or 3.0)? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html for the Oracle API, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html for Saxon 9.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example using javax.xml:

```
/**
 * Write the xml report to the file.
 *
 * NB: Transforms it into html on the fly.
 *
 * @param file Where to put it.
 * @param xml - What to put in it.
 */
protected void writeReport(File file, StringBuilder xml) {
    try {
        // Transform it through the xsl.
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("SavedReport.xsl"));
        // Build a transformer.
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        // Make URIs resolve to the same location as the xsl.
        transformer.setURIResolver(justTheNameMeansLocal);
        // Make a string stream out of the xml.
        Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        // Transform it straight into the output file.
        try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stream);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.writeLog(ME + "writeReport", ex, Logger.LOG_ERROR);
    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        Logger.writeLog(ME + "writeReport", ex, Logger.LOG_ERROR);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.writeLog(ME + "writeReport", ex, Logger.LOG_ERROR);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.writeLog(ME + "writeReport", ex, Logger.LOG_ERROR);
    }
}

/**
 * Resolve URI that are just a name to local.
 */
static class JustTheNameMeansLocal implements URIResolver {

    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        // Name only - resolve to local - otherwise hand off the resolution to default.
        return href.contains("\\") ? null : new StreamSource(SavedHTMLReport.class.getResourceAsStream(href));
    }

}
private static final URIResolver justTheNameMeansLocal = new JustTheNameMeansLocal();
// Transformer factory.
protected static final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

Comment: Hi @OldCurmudgeon, i understood the logic through simple example given by you. Can the same code be applied when i want to apply multiple XSLT in sequence on an XML file. i.e Output of first transformation should be used as input of the second transformation,...

Comment: @Sonu - Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4571956/823393) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1312406/823393).