# Use Result of java XSL transformation as a Stylesheet of a subsequent transformation

Tags: java, xslt, transform, sax, pipeline

I am trying to use the **result** of an java xsl transform (from XMLSource1.xml and StyleSheet1.xsl) as a **stylesheet** for another transform (from XMLSource2) and then output the result.

I read an interesting article about [chaining transformations](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2009/01/xml-and-xslt-tips-and-tricks-for-java.html) (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312406/efficient-xslt-pipeline-in-java-or-redirecting-results-to-sources) but what I am trying to achieve is slightly different because the result of the first transformation will not be the source for the second one but the **stylesheet** that should be apply to another transformation.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular difficulty in doing this and it's common practice.

To generate instructions like `xsl:value-of` without them being interpreted as instructions, use `xsl:namespace-alias`. There's an example in the XSLT specification itself.