# Best practice to generate a specific XML from given Java objects

Tags: java, xml, object

**Setting**

There's an old application that generates a report as a PDF. It uses an XML document (containing the report data) and an XSLT (describing the report layout) together with Apache FOP to generate the PDF. This application is going to be replaced by a new application.

The new application contains the report data as Java Beans (they're Hibernate annotated entities). There's no XML document anymore.

**Intention**

To "save" time it's been decided that the XSLT should be kept as is. Also the Apache FOP library is used again. This leaves the XML document.

The intention is to somehow take the Java object tree (hibernate entities) representing the report data and generate an XML document in such a way that it's still understood by the given XSLT (without changing the XSLT).

**Proposed Solution**

1. Create a second object tree based on the Hibernate object tree representing the report data. (Also annotate Hibernate annotated entities with JAXB annotation seems wrong.)
2. Annotate the new report-data-only classes with JAXB 2 annotations in such a way that they are marshaled to an XML document that's similar enough to the old XML document understood by the XSLT.

**Problem**

- Proposed solution takes a lot of time writing Java classes modelling more or less the intended XML document structure.

**Question**

Is there a better and faster way?

It seems that one just wants to "write down" the XML document containing the report data filled in at the "right" places.

The possible solution space is very open. What would you use and why?

- JAXB 2
- XMLStreamWriter?
- Groovy?
- Scala?
- Something else?

**Note**

- There is no XML Schema or DTD for the required XML document.
- Relates to [Best practices and design guidelines on composing XML with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552312/best-practices-and-design-guidelines-on-composing-xml-with-java)

Comment: Groovy can be a pretty easy way to build XML, and is worth checking out.  Check out the Groovy XML Builder feature.  Just FYI, it's also pretty easy to read XML using Groovy (XML Slurper).  Might be good to know someday.

Comment: @MikeThomas I tend to agree as it goes in the direction of just "writing down the XML". For example using [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder) seems just do that. The only question that remains is how easy it'd be to put the data from the POJOs into that structure (I imagine it to be easy) as well as how it performs for larger documents?

Comment: Building a dynamic document from POJOs will be a bit trickier than the usual static examples, but for avoiding tooling it's a very nice solution.  We used Groovy to format simple XML-over-HTTP responses in a project, and it was perfect for those small documents.  Slurper was also perfect for consuming smaller documents.  Larger documents may give you pause as the code may turn out less readable en masse, in which case a serialization approach _may_ be better, as others have mentioned.  YMMV as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JAXB to transform your document from POJO to XML. Then use XSLT to transform the XML to format that your current XSLT expects: JAXBSource -> XSLT -> XSLT-> DOMResult/StreamResult -> PDF.

Check [Efficient XSLT pipeline in Java (or redirecting Results to Sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312406/efficient-xslt-pipeline-in-java-or-redirecting-results-to-sources) for information about how to chain multiple transforms.

Comment: Your answer seems similar to the one from @GerritCap. Instead of using JAXB he suggests to use the XMLEncoder. The idea is the same, first materialize an XML with some structure and then apply an XSLT transformation to transform it into the expected report data XML structure.

Comment: XMLEncoders output format is not the easiest to work with. Also, you can't chain xslts with XMLEcoder

Comment: Reading @MikeThomas last comment I think my question has been answered and I'd think your approach is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions come into my mind,

One is to use java.beans.XMLEncoder and create a generic pro-processing xslt that transforms the XMLEncoder generated xml into the current xml data

Two is to write your own xml generator, possible falling back to reflection (directly or via java.beans.BeanDeescriptor) to make your code generic.

Comment: The first approach is to just dump the POJOs to XML then work out an XSLT transforming the dumped XML into the desired XML. Ok. (However, I'm not super excited about writing XSLT but that's only my personal point of view).
Writing my own XML generator doesn't seem like a quick (and best) solution to the problem. I'd think your first answer is better.