# Executing an XML with number of xls-transformations in sequence using Java Method

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I was able to succeed writing a method with one XML and one XSLtranformation.

But my another requirement is executing more than one XSL transformations in sequence. i.e Output of first transformation should be used as input of the subsequent transformation,...Something like as follows

```
public static String transformer(InputStream xml, List<InputStream> xsltInputStreamChain) {

}
```

I am not getting idea how this can be achieved.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_pipeline ?

Comment: Hi @Michael, Yes i opened this Wikipedia. The one which i need is also same. "For instance, given two transformations T1 and T2, the two can be connected so that an input XML document is transformed by T1 and then the output of T1 is fed as input document to T2. Simple pipelines like the one described above are called linear; a single input document always goes through the same sequence of transformations to produce a single output document."                  But how to achieve this XML_Pipeline

Comment: See whether http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312406/efficient-xslt-pipeline-in-java-or-redirecting-results-to-sources helps.

Comment: the link provided is more confusing to understand for beginners :-(